# How to use both versions of jar in a Java project?

Tags: java, jar, jvm

### 1. Background

`bcprov-jdk15on-1.54.jar`has been introduced into the project and is used in many places.

Now the partner has sent a new set of access information, which contains the following jar packages.

```bash
bcprov-jdk15on-1.69.jar
fintech-java-sdk-core-3.1.0.jar
fintech-java-sdk-kdft-3.1.0.jar
```

### 2. Questions

There are two versions of bcprov-jdk15on in the project, the old one is' 1.54 'and the new one is' 1.69'.

Something like this:

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMJ1J.png)

Since the '1.54' version is used in many places, it is not possible to upgrade directly to '1.69'.

Now I want to achieve the following two points:
`

- For the new version, `bcprov-jdk15on-1.69.jar` must be used for `fintech-java-sdk-core-3.1.0.jar` and `fintech-java-sdk-kdft-3.1.0.jar`
- For previous versions, leave `bcprov-jdk15on-1.54.jar` unchanged and use this version.

That is, the upgrade does not affect the historical function.

### 3 My analysis

If you do not consider the conflict case, the new jar is used normally, the example code is as follows:

```java
DefaultKdClient defaultKdClient = KdSdkConfig.getDefaultClient();

DemoApiInfo demoApiInfo = new DemoApiInfo();
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
DefaultKdRequest<Object> kdRequest = new DefaultKdRequest<>(demoApiInfo,
params);
```

I have thought about using class loaders, may be understanding is not yet in place, I think it is more troublesome to introduce every class like 'DefaultKdClient'

```java
// custom class loader: CustomClassLoader
CustomClassLoader classLoader = new CustomClassLoader();
Class<? > defaultKdClient = classLoader.loadClass("xx.DefaultKdClient");
```

And I'm not sure that this will ensure that the `bcprov-jdk15on` dependencies in `fintech-java-sdk-core-3.1.0.jar` and `fintech-java-sdk-kdft-3.1.0.jar` will be version `1.69`.

In addition, I also thought about creating a new project, keeping different JVMS, so that bcprov-jdk15on no longer conflicts, but new projects require new maintenance costs, and this approach does not feel good.

### 4. Questions

The above scene, what is the better solution, thank you~

Comment: If at all possible, don't. Just upgrade your existing code to work with the new version. It's only a few minor versions, so how hard could it be?

Comment: @Jorn normally you're right - just use the new version everywhere. However, I've had issues with BC before where something that _looked like_ a minor version had breaking changes.

Comment: @Jorn@Rob Spoor
Thank you for your comments.
If it were me, I would try to make the dependencies in the project not conflict. Actually, this is not my project, and there are other reasons why I can't do it now. I mainly want to know if there are any good solutions under the current background.